# Ubuntu 21.10 is booting very slowly, and systemd is not recognising it

Tags: boot

I have just done an installation of ubuntu 21.10, erasing all. On windows, my computer was able to boot in less than 10 seconds, but on ubuntu it is taking a minute and 40 now, (and has taken as long as 6 minutes with software installed in the past).

I have tried to work out what's causing it with systemd-analyze, but that reports a startup time of just 20 seconds, which isn't correct. The only thing that has had any impact was turning on secure boot, which somehow shortened the boot to 30 seconds, but that hasn't worked the second time. Any suggestions on what might be causing this that isn't showing up in systemd?

UPDATE: Issue fixed when changing the kernel from 5.13.0-23 to 5.13.0-25. I was able do this by spamming esc on startup and then booting a different kernel through the advanced option. This was after trying to download kernel 5.16. Now boots in 10 seconds.

Update 2: I had another issue with shutdown and restart not working. Changing to kernel 5.13.0-051300 has fixed shutdown and restart whilst still having 10 second boot.

Comment: Are you comparing a cold boot with windows (ie. *full boot time*) or with *fast-boot* enabled (*which is really a resume from a hibernate file created on your last update to enable fastboot*).  You've provided details are sparse & vague (FYI:  Ubuntu releases are *year.month* in format with no releases for 2021-January or 21.01; 1 & 10 are different numbers; are you using Ubuntu?)

Comment: i wonder what specs your computer has if it boots windows in 10sec because i want to get one.

Comment: To be precise, I am using ubuntu 21.10, and I am comparing the time between reaching the password screen on windows and the desktop itself on ubuntu, because I enabled auto login on ubuntu. However, when using windows it took no additional time after password was entered to reach the desktop.

Comment: I am not sure exactly what boot setting I had on windows, I can't go back and check as of now, I'm thinking I might be able get it back with a VM or something, because I didn't do the backup properly. I know I did not change any of the default settings if that helps. My guess is that it was a full boot.

Comment: My computer is a dell inspiron 5485 2-in-1. Specs aren't great but they're good enough for me.